# OpenGL VAO, VBO equivalent in DirectX11

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am working on implementing a directx11 instance of our game engine and I am a newbie in 3d game programming.

I know a little about DirectX11 graphics pipeline and shaders and what vertex buffers, input layout, etc are.

While looking at the one of the APIs the code is something like:

```
glBindVertexArray(current_vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, current_vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vector3) * Vertices.size(), &Vertices.front(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3), reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(5);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(6);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

What is this `VAO` and `VBO` equivalent in `DirectX11` ? What exactly is this code doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "VBO" is just a vertex buffer, which in DirectX 11 is a `ID3D11Buffer` with a bind flag of `D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER` which contains the vertex data.

There is no direct equivalent to the OpenGL "Vertex Attribute Array". In DirectX 11, you just submit a distinct `Draw` for each group of like state settings (a.k.a material attribute).

> If you are complete new to DirectX 11, you might consider working through the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials.